# Filter in Javascript not filtering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making a tour website using React as practice where a couple of locations with their images, descriptions as well as prices are presented and a button is added on each location where it removes a location from the site.

The function passed to the button is 'handleRemoval' whose code is as follows:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Tours from'./tours.js'
import datas from './toursData.js'

function App() {

  const [locations, setLocations] = useState([datas])

  const handleRemoval = (id) =>{
  const newLocations = locations.filter(location => location.id !== id);
  console.log(newLocations); //checking whether locations is filtered
  setLocations(newLocations);
}
return (
    <Tours tours={datas} handleRemoval={handleRemoval}/>
);
}
```

When I click the button and check the console I find that locations is not filtered and I don't understand why pls help :(

Github also happens to be showing errors so if you need the full code I'll just send it to you

Comment: ReactJS state updates are asynchronous ...

Comment: You're passing `datas` to your `Tours` component, but `datas` is never changed. Do mind that if `datas` is already an array, then `[datas]` will be an array inside of an array. Would you mind sharing an example of `datas` and the `id` that is passed to the function?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I hate how a simple mistake cracked my brain for hours lol... The function works perfectly although another bug just presented itself :'(

Comment: Ps. bug is fixed too thank you very much for your help